# How to detect if the contact that i'm calling to is already talking

Tags: java, android, phone-call

How to detect if the contact that i'm calling to is already talking?

Let's say I'm calling line 2 and I'm line 1 I want to know if Line 2 is already in a call with someone else.

Comment: i could be wrong but i dont think this is possible to check before the call is actually placed.

Comment: Firstly , Thanks for replying , secondly Let's say that the call IS placed , How can I do it?